# how to find drop down selected item text in controller in http post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am binding a drop down in a MVC 3 app. While I am doing POST, the model contain the selected value of drop down in property "SelectedWidgetId" (the **Id**), this is fine.

But I also want to see the selected Item TEXT in another property "SelectedWidgetText" (the **Name**)?

After search I find one way to find the drop down selected item text, but it's not directly? Looking for some other way? Suggest!

```
model.SelectedWidgetText = m.WidgetList.Where(e => e.Value == m.SelectedWidgetId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Text;
```

Here is all the code,

**Model**

```
public class Widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetModel
{
    private Widget[] Widgets
    {
        get
        {
            return new Widget[] { 
            new Widget { Id=1, Name="Item 1" },
            new Widget { Id=2, Name="Item 2" },
            new Widget { Id=3, Name="Item 3" }
        };
        }
    }
    public SelectList WidgetList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(Widgets.ToList(), "Id", "Name", SelectedWidgetId);
        }
    }
    public int SelectedWidgetId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedWidgetText { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new WidgetModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(WidgetModel model)
    {
        model.SelectedWidgetText = model.WidgetList.Where(e => e.Value == model.SelectedWidgetId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Text;
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedWidgetId, Model.WidgetList, "Select...");      
<input type='submit' />                                                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish your requirement you have to do :

I m using your `public string SelectedWidgetText { get; set; }` property of model class.

Use some jquery :

```
<script>
$("#SelectedWidgetId").on("change", function {
   $("#SelectedWidgetText").val($(this).text());
});
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(WidgetModel model,string SelectedWidgetText) 
{
  // do something with SelectedWidgetText value
}
```

Comment: well, approach is OK, again Indirect...also need to put more code, if dropdown is not change, any other way guys?

Comment: @user584018...In my opinion this is the only clean way to achieve desired functionality and the question you are putting if dropdown will not change then on document.ready put intially selected text of dropdown inside SelectedWidgetText with jquery...

Comment: the functionality which you want can't be acheieved due to the architecture of mvc on controller side you can only get value of dropdown not text...

Comment: Ohhh...Great..But if i get another answer of your question i will let you know...Thankzz...@user584018